# Which one is the difference in protege 5.0 (owl) between defined class and primitive class?

Tags: owl, protege, protege4

I read the manual of PRÖTEGË 5 in http://wiki.opensemanticframework.org/index.php/Adding_an_Ontology_Concept_using_Prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9 but I don´t understand , I am using the methodology "METHONTOLOGY" for the construction the Ontology.and I have some doubts for the implementation in Protege 5

Someone have a better manual for use PROTEGE 5

Comment: And what is the exact question now? By the way, I could not find the term "primitive class" in the link you provided. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

A defined class is a class involved in an axiom like `C equivalent some Property D`. A primitive class is one for which no such definition exists.

These concepts are explained in description logic books (e.g., the Description Logic Handbook), and their application in OWL is described in the W3C specs.